# What does 300+300mbps on a wireless router mean?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

I'm looking at a router on amazon, the netgear n600. I'm getting it for the dualband. Well one of the features say 300+300mbps.

Does that mean each channel operates at 300 mbps?
Does it achieve 600mbps?

Answer (score 2):

#### N600 WiFi Router 802.11n Dual Band Gigabit

The router has Simultaneous dual band 2.4GHz & 5GHz.

What does this mean? See below.

---

#### Why Should I choose Simultaneous Dual Band?

> **Why Choose Simultaneous Dual Band?**
>
> Dual Band Wireless Routers have the capability to transmit on the 5
> GHz and 2.4 GHz wireless band.
>
> 2.4GHz though more widespread in usage (all 802.11b and g devices run on 2.4GHz only) has only 3 non-overlapping channels for transmission,
> which are crowded due to a lot of interfering devices- other Wi-Fi
> access points, microwave ovens, cordless phones, Bluetooth devices,
> baby monitors, etc. all make for a noisy environment which increase
> interference and degrade the performance.
>
> 5GHz channel is much cleaner with less interference with 23
> non-overlapping channels- 8 times more than 2.4GHz for transmission,
> which makes it suitable for applications like Video streaming and
> Gaming which are very sensitive to packet loss and delays.
>
> There are two types of Dual Band Routers in the market: Simultaneous
> and Selectable Dual Band Routers with very different capabilities and
> performance:
>
> [image]

Source [Why Choose Simultaneous Dual Band?](http://www.netgear.com/landing/dual-band.aspx)

---

#### Netgear N600 wireless specifications

> WiFi Performance
>
> - N600 (300 Mbps + 300 Mbps)†
>
> WiFi Range
>
> - Medium to large homes
>
> WiFi Band
>
> - Simultaneous dual band 2.4GHz & 5GHz

Source  [N600 WiFi Router 802.11n Dual Band Gigabit](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-routers/wndr3700.aspx#tab-techspecs)